# If I have only 1 Database, should I use 1 or several Datasets in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

My Visual Studio application has several Window Forms, those forms use several Stored Procedures. What is the best practice, creating one Dataset for each stored procedure or adding all the stored procedures to the same Dataset1?

Comment: I think I found my answer: Since a Dataset keeps the data in memory, if I need only couple tables out of a large database, it's probably better to use a Dataset with only the appropriate tables. I still don't know though if I should regroup them in 1 dataset or several.